# Migrate AWS Amplify Prod live domain "abc.io" to Cloudfront + S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront, aws-amplify, cname

Frontend hosted on AWS amplify with custom domain "abc.io" cost high and the data loaded from amplify it takes too much time for high images and video to serve, with that the costing is getting more and more. For better performance on my requirements i need to use s3 + Cloudfront. I have already deployed my application in s3 and used Cloudfront but i need to change my domain "abc.io" from amplify and point it to Cloudfront, tried to add CNAME on Cloudfront but seems like already added by default amplify use Cloudfront CNAME. Please suggest me how to change the live domain used by amplify to Cloudfront where static object is from S3.

Note: This is a production domain and already live, though the domain propagation takes time please suggest the best option to migrate the domain.

I have tried to add CNAME from cloudfront for "abc.io" within a hosted zone but seems like it already exists from amplify.
Also i have already setup ssl certificate too and expect to migrate from amplify CNAME to cloudfront + s3 and remove the amplify service.